# Confused about SharePoint Standard version search features

Tags: search, sharepoint-on-prem

I read about SharePoint 2013-on prem.
That the standard version cannot do content search 
As a proof the web parts are also not included in standard version.

However strangely central admin, there default crawl on the local site.
It seams possible to add more crawl sources including external file servers.
Then if it cannot do content search what does it do ?

Comment: Can you add a link to the source you mention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enterprise search in SharePoint 2013 is really only:

1. Content Search Web Part
2. Custom Entity Extraction
3. Extensible Content Processing
4. Advanced actions on Query Rules
5. Video Search

The differences from Foundation to Standard are too many to list separately mentioned in table given in below link.

[On-Premise SharePoint 2013 Edition Comparison–Search](http://blog.randomdust.com/2013/01/on-premise-sharepoint-2013-edition-comparisonsearch/)

Comment: content search as you wrote is a web part in 2013 entp, 
so content search is not available in standard version, right ?

Comment: Yes it is not available in Standard Version.

Comment: So despite central admin allows for adding external file shares, it cannot search them on content, right ?.

Comment: Yes man... its true.

Comment: Is above information helps you?

Comment: Yes, thats kinda weird isnt it ?.

Comment: Yes.. Can you please mark the answer as it helps you?

Comment: Wait now what. Of course you can search for the files. You can use a search center site or any other search page. Or the Search Results webpart. The only thing is that the "Content by Search webpart" is not available in the Standard edition - but this is just a "nicer" webpart

Answer (score 3):

Please don't confuse "Content Search" with a "Content By Search Web Part". SharePoint Standard does crawl and index the contents of files. Rather than use CBS web part you can use the Search Results web part to do the same thing. And YES you can get results from file shares. Also, the Video results is a misnomer. You can easily recreate the Video Results Result Source.

Comment: Do you say here that if a word document contains a specific word, that sharepoint standard version can find the word or not?, because i read that it cannt do that, just like te previous poster noted it cannt do that. Keep in mind that standard has limitations as compared to enterprice version

Comment: Of course it can, see my comment above

Comment: Yes, if any of the standard office documents and (and PDFs in 2013/2016) are crawled the contents is extracted. Standard is "limited" only in the web parts. It's the same search engine. Where did you "read that" info?

Comment: actually at various places even some at Microsoft

Comment: Without a specific citation I can only guess that you are misunderstanding the document. Search in Standard is the same as search in Enterprise. There are specific extension and implementation differences, but most can be overcome if you know what you are doing.